# any guide to write my own barcode scanner instead of zxing?

Tags: android, barcode

anybody knows any article or a place to start to write a simple barcode scanner just for 2d QR barcode?

I don't want to user zxing library as much as I can  .

and I use android if it helps.

thank you

Comment: Did u found any solution on the same. I also need same thing in one of android project. Plz let me know if you found

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of (quite expensive) libraries for java:

http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.barcode-for-java/default.aspx

http://www.onbarcode.com/products/java_barcode_reader/

A quite nice article on how to implement it on c#: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/barcodeimaging2.aspx

and another (open source) c# project here: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/barbara/

You could try porting those.